# Marking Duplicates while ignoring null values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to highlight duplicates values in my df by using below code.

```
ncns['D-Account'] = ncns.duplicated('Account Number')
```

Although it marks the duplicates correctly, but it also marks the blank values as duplicate.

Please suggest something so that it should ignore blank values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If blank are missing values chain mask for test non misisng values by `&` for bitwise `AND` with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
ncns['D-Account'] = ncns.duplicated('Account Number') & ncns['Account Number'].notna()
```

If blanks are empty strings compare non `''` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
ncns['D-Account'] = ncns.duplicated('Account Number') & ncns['Account Number'].ne('')
```

Comment: pretty slick answer